# Unlimited scroll json get new result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working on a unlimited scroll of information.

I've an call on a jquery function that using slice in an .each function, as default it is 10, but i want, if you scroll down the amount will rise * 2 times.

But everytime i'll scroll he'll add the same below it with more new items.

But what i want is, that i have the same 10 items and when i scroll that 10 or more new items will show below that default amount of items.

code:

```
var win = $(window);
// Each time the user scrolls
win.scroll(function() {
    // End of the document reached?
    if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
        $('#loading').show();

        getEvents(10 * 2);

    }
});
```

I like to hear from you, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ajax response return only 10 items every call, so :

1st call with getEvents(0,10); return an array of 10 elements

2nd calls with getEvents(10,20); return the next 10 elements

...

N calls with getEvents(N * 10, N+1 * 10);

in your function do so :

```
// on page load run :
getEvents(10 , 20 );
// add counter 
var counter = 2;
// Each time the user scrolls
win.scroll(function() {
  // End of the document reached?
  if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
    $('#loading').show();

    getEvents(counter * 10 , ++counter * 10 );

  }
});
```

also, **try to debounce the scroll event**.

i hope this help

Comment: Thanks but the getEvents() function expect 2 paramters. Because i work with slice() on my each(), like 0 to 10 events, and i want everytime i scroll i want to have * 2, so. first attempt 0 to 10, second 10 to 20 etc. etc.

Comment: thanks man, but now the problem is that the first attempt i get the same items only by the second attempt the new stuff shows. :S

Comment: @PieterDijkstra you should keep track of your last loaded element some way. I don't know your sorting mode, but i hope that you don't have elements that can be inserted between others, like we had in some project, or else that will be complex (congrats for your pathfinding stuff btw :P)

Comment: Thanks @Kaddath, we have no sorting mode. It is simple an ajax call on a json output. and with a each() i'll show the elements

Comment: @Aissam, Your edit didn't fix the problem, isn't possible that by the first attempt of scrolling he start by 10 to 20 and not 0 to 10 ? Can you edit this in your script :D